# Find an element's attribute in a list of sets of elements

Tags: java, performance, collections

I need to find an element's key that's in a list of sets of elements.  What's a better (faster) way to do it?  Here's my code:

```
// get tags from an ArrayList of resources
boolean tagFound = false;
HashSet<Tag> resourceTags = new HashSet<>();
for (Resource resource : list) {
    Set<Tag> tmpTags = resource.getTags();
    resourceTags.addAll(tmpTags);
}

// get tag keys from all tags
for (Tag resourceTag : resourceTags) {
    if (resourceTag.getKey().equals(tag.getKey())) {
        tagFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is tag ? Please insert tag initialization code as well.

Comment: Is method `getTags()` a static method of class `Resource` as shown in the code you posted?

Comment: @Naman I'm guessing you edited the original code and changed `Resource.getTags()` to `resource.getTags()`. If you did, then how can you be sure that the OP did not **intentionally** write `Resource.getTags()` ?

Comment: @Abra Well, of course, I intuitively did that inferring from the question that the code is correct and the traditional `for-each` used there would have otherwise had unused `resource`. I am not denying that it could have been put that way, just trying to correct a possible typo.

Comment: @Naman Thank you, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply get rid of the `addAll` overhead if all you're going to do is iterate again over it to find an occurrence.

```
for (Resource resource : list) {
    for (Tag resourceTag : resource.getTags()) {
        if (resourceTag.getKey().equals(tag.getKey())) {
            tagFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If this was to be written in a functional manner, it would look like:

```
boolean tagFound = list.stream()
        .flatMap(r -> r.getTags().stream())
        .anyMatch(t -> t.getKey().equals(tag.getKey()));
```

***Note***: On performance, in an **R x T** matrix you would have to pay `O(R x T)` runtime to search for an element unless they are hashed. In the latter case, if for example `Tag` was hashed you could have simply performed a `contains` based on the `key` to lookup in `O(1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the keys in the set instead of the tags themselves, then use the `contains` method. The code below assumes the keys are strings.

```java
Set<String> resourceTagKeys = new HashSet<>();
for(Resource resource : list) {
    for(Tag t : resource.getTags()) {
        resourceTagKeys.add(t.getKey());
    }
}
boolean tagFound = resourceTagKeys.contains(tag.getKey());
```

That said, it doesn't make much sense to build the set if you're just going to test one element. If you are going to test multiple keys, then you can build the set once, and query it in a separate method. Otherwise, this way is simpler:

```java
boolean tagFound = false;

outer:
for(Resource resource : list) {
    for(Tag t : resource.getTags()) {
        if(t.getKey().equals(tag.getKey())) {
            tagFound = true;
            break outer;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is in a method returning `tagFound`, then you can avoid the labelled `break` by just writing `return true;` in the loop. If it's not in a method, you might consider refactoring it so that it is.